# loops efficiency

Tags: android, loops, performance

I came across through a presentation([dalvik-vm-internals](http://sites.google.com/site/io/dalvik-vm-internals)) on Dalvik VM, in that it is mentioned as for the below loops, we have **use (2) and (3)** and to **avoid (7)**.

(1) for (int i = initializer; i >= 0; i--)

(2) int limit = calculate limit;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)

(3) Type[] array = get array;
for (Type obj : array)

(4) for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

(5) for (int i = 0; i < this.var; i++)

(6) for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++)

(7) Iterable list = get list;
for (Type obj : list)

Comments: i feel that (1) and (2) are the same.
(3)
(4) every time it has to calculate the length of array, so this can be avoided
(5) 
(6) same as (4), calculating the size everytime
(7) asked to avoid as list is of an Iterable type??

one more, in case if we have infinite data(assume data is coming as a stream) which loop should we consider for better efficiency?)

request you to please comment on this...

Comment: That presentation is from 2008, well before the JIT compiler was introduced in Froyo.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach is newer but I think that document is also a bit out of date.  (An updated version should show up on that site when the next release goes out.)

Comment: Thanks for the link!! that was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's what they recommend, that's what they've optimized the compiler and VM for. The ones you feel are the same aren't necessarily implemented the same way: the compiler can use all sorts of tricks with data and path analysis to avoid naively expensive operations. For instance, the `array.length()` result can be cached since arrays are immutable.

They're ranked from most to least efficient: but (1) is 'unnatural'. I agree, wouldn't you? The trouble with (7) is that an iterator object is created and has to be GC'ed.

Note carefully when the advice should be heeded. It's clearly intended for **bounded** iteration over a known collection, not the stream case. It's only relevant if the loop has significant effect on performance and energy consumption ('operating on the computer scale'). The first law of optimization is "Don't optimize". The second law (for experts) is "Don't optimize, yet.". Measure first (both execution times and CPU consumption), optimize later: this applies even to mobile devices.

What you should consider is the preceding slides: try to sleep as often and as long as possible, while responding quickly to changes. How you do that depends on what kind of stream you're dealing with.

Finally, note that the presentation is two years old, and may not fully apply to 2.2 devices where among other things JIT is implemented.

Comment: Yes, i think i simplified!! but does it have any difference between (1) and (2), because of the post-decrement and post-increment?

Comment: See my revision. Comparison to an arbitrary integer is usually implemented as a subtraction and comparison to zero, hence (1) has a very slight edge in performance over (2), but requires us to think backwards (and makes the code a touch less maintainable). Go for (1) only if you **know** there's a performance bottleneck or CPU power hotspot in that code. And even then...

Answer (score 0):

With infinite data, none of the examples are good enough.  Best would be to do

```
for(;;) {
   list.poll(); //handle concurrency, in java for example, use a blocking queue
}
```

Comment: does it have any difference if we use... while(1) {list.poll();} ?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, no.

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) are really different. 2) need an extra subtraction to compute i=0 doesn't. 
Even better, on most processor (and well optimized code) no is comparison needed for i>=0. The processor can use the the [negative flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register), resulting for the last decrement (i--).

So the end of the loop -1 looks like (in pseudo assembler)

```
--i
jump-if-neg
```

while loop #2

```
++i
limit-i  # set negative flag if i >limit
jump-if-neg
```

That doesn't make a big difference, except if the code in your loop is really small (like basic C string operation)
That might not work with interpreted languages.